# What is the best way to process XML sent to WCF 3.5

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, xml-parsing

I have to develop a WCF application in 3.5. The input will be sent in the form of XML and the response would be sent in the form of XML as well. A ASP.NET application will be consuming the WCF and sending/receiving data in XML format.

Now, as per my understanding, when consuming WCF from an ASP.NET application, we just add a reference to the service, create an object of the service, pack all the necessary data(Data Members in WCF) into the input object (object of the Data Contract) and call the necessary function.

It happens that the ASP.NET application is being developed by a separate party and they are hell bent on receiving and sending data in XML format. What I can perceive from this is that the WCF will take the XML string (a single Data Member string type) as input and send out a XML string (again a single Data Member string type) as output. I have created WCF applications earlier where requests and responses were sent out in XML/JSON format when it was consumed by jQuery ajax calls. In those cases, the XML tags were automatically mapped to the different Data Members defined.

What approach should I take in this case? Should I just take a string as input (basically the XML string) or is there any way WCF/.NET 3.5 will automatically map the XML tags with the Data Members for requests and responses and I would not need to parse the XML string separately?

Comment: From what I can tell, you're in the fortunate position of developing a service for a client which has not yet been written. I would use DataContracts as normal, then hand them an auto-generated WSDL document to run through `svcutil`. They can thank you for making their jobs easier later :) I've been on the client side of this equation for a *service* whose single call accepted and returned a string parameter encoded as XML, which had to be manually decoded. All wrapped in a SOAP envelope :P

Comment: Generally people spec web services or clients this way because they don't actually understand the technology they're using.  I feel quite strongly about this kind of thing - it's a bloody farce!

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

However you can just 'shell' your own instance of the `DataContractSerializer` to deserialize/serialize the actual objects from/to the XML strings that your caller wants.  Then you're still free to write data contract types at your end which mirror those that the caller wants to use.

If they expect you to be able to get that into the WSDL of the service, however, then they're barking up the wrong tree - you'd need to publish the schema for those types separately (you can use the `XsdDataContractExporter` to do that).

On another note - it's **deeply** disturbing that these guys want you to develop a WCF service which simply chucks XML strings around.  Given that WCF will use XML as the message format anyway, all this XML will have to be sent as naked (either encoded or CDATA) text and so there'll be no message-level validation of the XML.  Your code will always receive request, regardless of whether the XML string supplied is gobbledegook or not.  It's incredibly hacky.

Answer (score 0):

In its normal configuration, WCF will send data over the as XML, so there is nothing you have to do about this. As I understand, that party has some `string` literal with XML and wants to pass it on to you directly, and they want to recieve XML from you directly. It would be rather awkward to send XML data, wrapped by XML. This way your service code will have to parse that XML instead of working with an object graph directly. I would give them the finger and tell that if they want to work with XML directly than that's their problem. They are trying to make this your problem, which is not fair. You just stick to good developement practices.